# Elementary Differential Equations, Boyce, section 2.2, exercise 19 (Separable Equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The exercise is to solve the initial value problem:

$$\sin{(2x)}\mathrm dx+\cos(3y)\mathrm dy = 0$$
$$y\left(\frac\pi2\right)=\frac\pi3$$

We get $\cfrac{-\cos{(2x)}}{2}+\cfrac{\sin{(3y)}}{3}=K$, and from $y\left(\frac\pi2\right)=\frac\pi3$ we conclude that
$$\cfrac{-\cos{(\pi)}}{2}+\cfrac{\sin{(\pi)}}{3}=K \Rightarrow K = \cfrac{1}{2}\text.$$ Then:
$$\cfrac{\sin{(3y)}}{3}=\cfrac{1}{2}+\cfrac{\cos{(2x)}}{2}=\cos^2{x} \implies \sin{(3y)}=3\cos^2{x}$$.

Why the solution is $y=\cfrac{\pi-\arcsin{\left(3\cos^2{x}\right)}}{3}$ and not simply $y=\cfrac{\arcsin{\left(3\cos^2{x}\right)}}{3}$? What am I doing wrong?

I would thank any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin(3y)=3\cos^2(x) \Rightarrow y= \dfrac{ \text{arcsin}(3\cos^2(x))}{3}$

When you do this, you are assuming that $\sin(3y)$ is invertible in a neighborhood of $\frac{ \pi}{2}$. But in every open ball centered in $\frac{ \pi}{2}$ exist points $a<   \frac{ \pi}{2}< b$ such that $\sin(3y(a))=\sin(3y(b))$ because of the square in $cos(x)$. Therefore you have to be careful when choosing the domain of your solution.

The solution $y= \dfrac{ \pi - \text{arcsin}(3\cos^2(x))}{3}$ is valid when $x \in [0, \dfrac{ \pi}{2} ]$ while $y= \dfrac{\text{arcsin}(3\cos^2(x))}{3}$ is valid when $x \in [\dfrac{ \pi}{2}, \pi ]$.

Comment: Why can't $y= \dfrac{\text{arcsin}(3\cos^2(x))}{3}$ be valid when $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ and the other solution be valid in $[\pi/2,\pi]$?